# Values of SM parameters at one certain scale

Tags: quantum-field-theory, research-level, standard-model, supersymmetry, renormalization

The general question is:
What are the values of Standard Model parameters (in the $\bar{MS}$ renormalization scheme) at some scale e.g. $m_{Z}$? As its parametrization in Yukawa matrices is not unique - what are the values of gauge couplings, fermion masses and CKM matrix?

The background:
I want to solve renormalization group equations of MSSM and in order to have initial conditions for them I need to know SM parameters at one scale - not at few different, which one can find at Particle Data Group webpage.

Comment: What's the matter with 'a few different' scales?  Since you know the standard model beta and gamma functions, why not use them to run all parameters to a common scale?

Answer (score 2):

See Appendix A of my PhD thesis: http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.1425
I worked out the values of the parameters to use in RGE at $\mu=M_Z$.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the place to start for you is the [Gfitter package](http://gfitter.desy.de). As I understand they have the best "global fit" of the SM parameters at $m_Z$.

Here is [the recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2716) which takes into account recently discovered *God pa ...*, sorry,  the Higgs boson.

Also note that they've partially done your work by considering [Type-II 2HDM](http://gfitter.desy.de/Two_Higgs_Doublet_Model/).

Hope that helps.